# Graph Beta RiskDetection API failing for queries with "less-than" $filter combined w/ "$top"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been querying the riskDetection API and filtering by the "DetectedDateTime" for pagination, and to get events only within a certain time range. This morning this API call started failing, only for one of our tenants, and only for the riskDetection endpoint (identityRiskEvents works fine)

I get the following error for queries involving `le`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "29ec0904-8655-43d2-a422-7e7554313906",
      "date": "2020-01-22T19:18:29"
    }
  }
}
```

```
// This one works
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$orderby=detecteddatetime+desc&top=500&filter=(detectedDateTime+ge+2020-01-19T18:06:04Z) 

// This one returns UnknownError
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$orderby=detecteddatetime+desc&top=500&filter=(detectedDateTime+ge+2020-01-19T18:06:04Z)

// This one works
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$orderby=detecteddatetime+desc&filter=(detectedDateTime+le+2020-01-19T18:06:04Z)
```

Seems like the combination of $top and $filter=detectedDateTime+le+... is causing errors. Has anyone encountered this recently / know if this is an issue on Microsoft's end, or an issue w/ my query syntax / something else?

Comment: Have tried your call but it works fine for the combination of $top and $filter=detectedDateTime+le. For this special case, please bring your request-id to the Azure Support team to locate the problem.